# why is this setting cookie in wordpress is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

This is my code to set cookie in `functions` but hook init is not working. How can i fix this issue?

```
function set_carts_cookies($carts_Items){
    global $carts;
    $carts=serialize($carts_Items);
    function setting_new_cookie() {
        global $carts;
        setcookie('cart_item',$carts,time() + (60),'/');
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'setting_new_cookie');
}
set_carts_cookies(array(1,2));
```

`echo $carts=serialize($carts_Items);` this line is working fine but unable to init hook.

Comment: Put you add_action(... line outside of your function set.... and see

Comment: add_action should work only after calling set_carts_cookies